# How should I install npm, I tried all of the command but none of worked for me

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

```
npm install
audited 17250 packages in 7.466s

26 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

My System Info:

1.OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name DESKTOP-7CV9HTK
System Manufacturer HP
System Model    HP ENVY Laptop 13-ah1xxx
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  5HZ05PA#AKL
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz, 1992 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Insyde F.12, 11/8/2018
SMBIOS Version  3.0
Embedded Controller Version 69.72
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  HP
BaseBoard Product   850B
BaseBoard Version   69.72
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   On
PCR7 Configuration  Elevation Required to View
Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.18362.387"
User Name   DESKTOP-7CV9HTK\Hanifullah Jamalzai
Time Zone   Afghanistan Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   15.8 GB
Available Physical Memory   9.89 GB
Total Virtual Memory    18.2 GB
Available Virtual Memory    10.3 GB
Page File Space 2.38 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection   Off
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled
Device Encryption Support   Elevation Required to View
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes

Comment: first of all you have to install node in your computer. and then you will be able to use npm install cammand

Comment: absolutely, I have node installed

Comment: First try $nodejs.-v if you found any response node is installed in your pc other wise you have to installed. @HanifullahJamalzai

Comment: @DipakDholakiya , Here You go: v12.14.1

Comment: @DipakDholakiya but this command is not working in vscode

Comment: Run it in command prompt @HanifullahJamalzai

Comment: @DipakDholakiya its working there

Comment: Yes my frnd @HanifullahJamalzai

Comment: I think I should my NodJs to 12.15

Comment: Please do not tag with Laravel, PHP, VueJS when this question has nothing to do with those. Also, please tell us a bit more about your environment. Is it a Linux machine (which I think it might be given the $ before the command) or a Windows by any chance? What command did you try to install npm?

To install on Debian based distros: `sudo apt install nodejs` and
npm will get installed with it. If not, do `sudo apt install npm`.

Comment: @QumberRizvi , Thank You brother, I am using windows 10, I used ( npm install ) for installing npm in my project. I am working in laravel and vuejs

Comment: I have upgraded my NodeJs still have the same issue

Comment: `npm install` is used to install Node packages not npm itself. If doing `npm --version` gives you a version, that means npm is already installed in your system. You can go ahead and install a package using it. To install Vue CLI, for example, try `npm install -g @vue/cli`. Here is a tutorial on setting up NodeJS and npm (you probably only need to to follow it upto step 5): https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-windows-10-tutorial/

Comment: Looks like you have successfully install npm packages from `package.json`. So, what your really problem?

Comment: @QumberRizvi its not working, show lot of errors, Bcoz, laravel v is 5.7

Comment: I want to install in laravel 5.7 @WahyuKristianto I checked right now there isnt npm

Answer (score 0):

Npm is recognized on cmd but not on vscode?
Assuming you are using windows, you need to update the path in environment/user variables AND restart vscode for it to recognize the changes.

Comment: I updated vs code and nodejs, but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had Yarn Package Manager which is an alternative to npm. The packages you are trying to install can not be installed with npm, "npm install" will not work because it is not the format used by yarn when you are trying to install some package.